# PHP Dynamic String manipulation

Tags: php, string

I am very new to PHP and this forum. I don't know whether my question will be suitable for this forum or not.

I have a string `$filter=([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ([type] = 'R,T');`
but in this string there is a dynamic value for value [type]
that means the value [type]='R,T' may be [type]='R,T,P' ..........

Now for each character content in the [type] should be change as -

```
([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ([type] ='R' OR [type] = 'T')
```

or

```
([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ([type] ='R' OR [type] = 'T' OR [type] = 'P')
```

.........................

for this I wrote a small code and it takes around 1 days.

```
$text = explode("[type] =",$filter);
$myreplacetext = "[type] = ".$text[1];
$text2 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.,]/s', '', $text[1]);
$string = explode(",", $text2);;
$i=0;
foreach($string as $value){
    $value = trim($value);
    if($i==0)$mynewtext = "'".$value."'";
    else $mynewtext = $mynewtext." OR [type] = '".$value."'";
    $i++;
}
$mynewtext = $mynewtext.")";
$filter = str_replace($text[1],$mynewtext,$filter);
```

Anyone please kindly guide me to write this code in a simple way

Comment: You need to write a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). This is much more complex than just exploding and regular expressions.

Comment: Is there a specific question you'd like answered? Asking us to re-write your code for you much past a suggestion such as @Barmar's is not going to go over well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Try this code. Any question, feel free to comment here.

```
    $filter = "([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ([type] = 'R,T,P')";
    $text = explode("[type] =",$filter);
    $firstPart = $text[0];
    $text2 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.,]/s', '', $text[1]);

    // now:
    // $firstPart sholud be like '([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ('
    // $text2 should be like 'a,b,c'
    $string = explode(",", $text2);
    $typeList = array();
    foreach ($string as $value)
    {
        $value = trim($value);
        if (!$value)
        {
            continue;
        }
        $typeList[] = "[type] = '$value'";
    }
    $typeStr = implode(' OR ', $typeList);

    // $firstPart sholud be like '([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ('
    // $typeStr should like: [type] ='R' OR [type] = 'T' OR [type] = 'P'

    // so the result should be:
    $filter = $firstPart . $typeStr . ')';
    echo $filter;
    // the output:  ([operator] = 'IDEA') AND ([type] = 'R' OR [type] = 'T' OR [type] = 'P')
```